# PHP automatic generation of links per month

Tags: php

This results in a constant loop and after some hours now i am too tired to find the problem.
This should be the result:
`<li><a href="monthly/13-7.php">Juli 2013</a></li><li><a href="monthly/13-8.php">August 2013</a></li>`

here the code i produced:

```
<?php
//array mit monaten
$monate = array(
    1 => "Januar", 
    2 => "Februar", 
    3 => "M&auml;rz", 
    4 => "April", 
    5 => "Mai", 
    6 => "Juni", 
    7 => "Juli", 
    8 => "August", 
    9 => "September", 
    10 => "Oktober", 
    11 => "November", 
    12 => "Dezember"
    );
//aktueller monat
$d = new DateTime('today');
$d->modify('first day of this month');
$lowmonth = $d->format('Y-m-d');
$highmonth = $d->format('ym');
$hm = (int)$highmonth;
$monat = date("n");
$pre = "<li><a href='monthly/";
$mid = ".php'>";
$end = "</a></li>";
$lm = 6;
$ly = 13;
$thim = $lm;
$thiy = $ly;
$ye = 0;
$dast = $ly.$lm;
$dat = (int)$dast;
while($dat < $hm)
    {
    if($thim == 12)
        {
        $ye = 1;
        $thiy++;
        }
    else
        {
        $ye = 0;
        }
    if($ye = 1)
        {
        $thim = 1;
        }
    else
        {
        $thim++;
        }
    echo $pre.$thiy."-".$thim.$mid.$monate[$thim]." 20".$thiy.$end;
    $dats = $thiy.$thim;
    $dat = (int)$dats;
    }
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Your code is a disaster to read.

Comment: i hate the formatting here... do it better if you want and get no error for "too much code"... grow older...

Comment: my question is: where is my error that it loops until death?!

Comment: You're using `DateTime()`, but doing your own manual date increments? Why can't you use a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/dateinterval)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
     $time = mktime(0,0,0,$i,1);
     print '<li><a href="monthly/'.date('y-m', $time)'.php">'.$monate[$i].' '.date('Y', $time).'</a></li>';
}
```

Should work? You could add a second for loop around this one that will loop years, so you can start from say 2012 and loop to the current year.